# Unable to figure out why I can't connect to mssql server with php

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Here is my call that is throwing a 500 error.

```
$myServer = "MICKMAN\Mickman";
$myUser = "tester";
$myPass = "tester";
$myDB = "movieDB"; 

$con = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass);
    if ( !$con )
    {
        die( 'Could not connect: '  );
    }
```

I'm using PHP 5.4, and phpinfo shows that sqlsvr is enabled. I added this extension to the php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
```

I've setup the ODBC in windows and created a user in MSSQL Studio.
I'm not sure what I am missing. The php error is not even displaying. I get a blank page when I attempt to access it.

I've connected to DBs before with PHP, but I've never set one up for a remote connection before. I've tried as many howto's as I could find and am still having the same issues.

Comment: You will be much better off using PDO to connect to an MSSQL database. It is much simpler, and much more supported :-)

Comment: Never output a fixed string as an error message when you can include ACTUAL details about the problem. Try `die('Connect not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SQL Server PDO Driver (more information [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)).

Once you have the driver installed and enabled, you can then test a connection like so:

```
try {
    $host = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=localhost;Database='.$database, $username, $password);
    foreach($host->query('SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $host = null;
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die('Connect not connect: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use [mssql_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php) which is provided by the [php_mssql.dll extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php).  This extension is no longer included with php (>5.3).  You should be using the functions provided by php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll which are prefixed with sqlsrv.

```
$myServer = "MICKMAN\Mickman";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "UID" => "tester"
,   "PWD" => "tester"
,   "Database" => "movieDB"
);

$con = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo);
if( $con === false ) {
    echo "Unable to connect.";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```